# JavaScript: Mobile number validation with numbers and max length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to have a JS which has the requirement as below

I have a textbox of type **number** and whenever i typed inside that textbox should **ONLY ALLOW** numbers [0-9] and it should **NOT ALLOW** the length of the numbers entered to  be more than 8 digits.

Eg:

```
12345678 - Allow
1234    - Dont Allow
1234%^  - Dont Allow
```

My Html:

```
<input type="number" id="txt_number" maxlength="8" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)">
```

My JS

```
 function isNumber(evt) {
evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57 ||charCode>=190)) {
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Please help me.

Appreciate.
Thanks

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: You have input type number so you don't need the function check like you are doing.

Comment: personnally, I use this solution in my code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29902316/4949388

Comment: You said the number cannot be more than 8 digits, but a number with 4 digits is not allowed either?  Maybe you mean the number can only have 8 digits.  Please make the requirements more clear in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use RegEx match:

```
function checkMonum(){
var input=document.getElementById('txt_number').value;
    var state=false;
    var re=/^[\d\.]{8}$/;
var output = re.test(input);
if(output==true){
   state=true;
}
return state;
}
```

i change method match with test, you can check in FF. i am on mobile in chrome. Exactly with 8 digits or has period

Comment: how to call this function? <input type="number" id="txt_number" maxlength="8" onkeypress="return checkMonum()">

Comment: Hi Kollein, i see it is allowing only numbers. But it allows . (dot decimal) as well.But i dont want the user to type any numbers above 8 digits length. I want to just allow only to have 8 digits. Any input above 8 digits length can be truncated

Comment: change to be:     var re=/^(\d|\.?){8}$/;

Comment: Hi Kollein, i tried the below function but it is not allowing any thing to type including numbers function checkMonum(){
 var input=document.getElementById('txt_number').value;
     var state=false;
     var re=/^(\d|\.?){8}$/;
 var output = input.match(re);
 if(output.length==8){
    state=true;
 }

Comment: because you set IF condition in wrong, must be: output.lenth>0

Comment: or set :if( output != null) , meaning input has matche with statement be enough 8 digits or has one char " dot decimal  "

Comment: Hi Kollein, the updated code of the JS is not allowing anything to type. Includes alphanumeric and special characters.. Can you please help. Thanks

Comment: answer above accepts: 8 digits or has a dot. You can check input='12345678' or input='1234.5678'

Comment: Hi Kollein, i see your code allows (.) dot   https://jsfiddle.net/SenthilRS/6gmc1ojq/4/   . i also see the JS not working in mozilla fire fox browser

Comment: work fine in Chrome, you should update the code above for checking again

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/SenthilRS/6gmc1ojq/6/    allows more than 8 digits length and also allows (.) dot. I used the above code you updated

Comment: if you want exactly 8 digits ?

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
 function isNumber(evt) {
 evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
 var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
 if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
     return false;
 }

 return true;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function () {
    $(".numericOnly").bind('keypress', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == '9' || e.keyCode == '16') {
            return;
        }
        var code;
        if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
        else if (e.which) code = e.which;
        if (e.which == 46)
            return false;
        if (code == 8 || code == 46)
            return true;
        if (code < 48 || code > 57)
            return false;
    }
    );
    $(".numericOnly").bind("paste", function (e) {
        $("#lblSearchError").text("Phone no must be numeric digit only !!!");
        $('#lblSearchError').show('slow').delay(3000).queue(function (n) {
            $(this).hide('slow'); n();
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $(".numericOnly").bind('mouseenter', function (e) {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val != '0') {
            val = val.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, "")
            $(this).val(val);
        }
    });
});
```

with this function you can restrict user to enter other than numeric values and user won't be able to past any non-numeric data. this works for me 
You can use it by class name or by ID

Comment: Hi Naveen, Can you please tell me how to call this js and what are the html changes required. i call my exisiting js as <input type="number" id="txt_number" maxlength="8" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)">

Comment: add  'numericOnly'  class to your input type control it will work <input type="number" id="txt_number" maxlength="8" class="numericOnly"> this only you have to do